# How to use a variable WS name that references another WS and a variable range, with a MIN function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a WS named Stats and I want to fill a column with the MINIMUMs.  The data is in the same WB, but on another WS called Data.
The data is in rows, so MIN calc would be performed on range B to IQ columns.
And I need to calc the MIN for rows 14 to 1868.

The following code works, but name and range of the data is hard coded:

```
Worksheets("Stats").Range("B14:B1868").Formula = "=MIN(Data!B58:IQ58)"
```

So my problem is that every workbook has a different worksheet name for the data.  My macro has to work for all WBs.

I've tried the Indirect function, and this configuration only works for one row of data and populates the rest of the column with the same number(note that $A$2 is the location with the Worksheet name that contains the data):

```
Worksheets("Stats").Range("B14:B1868").Formula = "=MIN(Indirect($A$2&""!B58:IQ58"")"
```

I have tried so many different configs and can't figure this one out. I'll get a name or a ref error...it's driving me nuts, hoping someone here can help me!

Thanks in advance:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cell reference's value just as easily as a string literal.

<sup>*(Sense of deja-vu there - I wrote that as part of an answer just this morning!)*</sup>

So, instead of hard-coding "Data" into the formula

```
Worksheets("Stats").Range("B14:B1868").Formula = "=MIN(Data!B58:IQ58)"
```

you can insert the value from a cell

```
Worksheets("Stats").Range("B14:B1868").Formula = "=MIN('" & Worksheets("Stats").Range("A2").Value & "'!B58:IQ58)"
```

(I added apostrophes around the sheet name as well, just in case it contained spaces or other special characters.)

Comment: I just joined tonight, do I need to close this out because its solved?

Comment: @iTry There should be a "tick" to the right of the answer.  You can click on that for whichever answer helped you the most.  An "accepted answer" gives the answerer +15 rep, and gives you +2 rep.  Later on, when you have more rep, you will also be able to vote up (or down) answers that are useful (or not).  Upvotes give answerers +10 rep.  Downvotes take 2 rep off the answerer (but costs the downvoter 1 rep too).

Comment: @iTry I don't think the "accept" was successful.  The "tick" should turn green if it was.  (And, oops, I just realised I don't know my left from my right - the tick should be on the **left** of the answer.)  If you can't get it to work, it probably doesn't matter much.  (I have 19000 rep already, another 15 isn't going to make much difference :D)  All that might happen is someone else might come along and try to give an even better answer!

Comment: YowE3K, I clicked on the checkmark and it turned green, hopefully it worked!  Sorry for not getting right the other day, was under the weather and exhausted...and every point counts and you sure deserve them!  I had just joined, and 23 min later, I had the solution!  I'm so impressed:-)  Happy Holidays from NH, USA!